# End of DATA on a FRAME

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write code for SDI-12 protocol

the byte frame format of SDI-12 is

- 1 start bit
- 7 data bits, least significant bit transmitted first
- 1 parity bit, even parity
- 1 stop bit

I want to transmit an 24 bits of data i.e., `100001101011001010000100`

which when arranged in frame looks like

start,1000011,P,stop, start,0101100,P,stop, start,1010000,P,stop, start,100_ _ _ _,P,stop

where P is a parity bit

the problem is:

- what data should I transmit in the last four bits i.e.,_ _ _ _
- how should i know that the data to be sent is completed?

CODE:

```
 library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
entity serialtx is
    generic (data_width : integer);
    port (clk, reset : in  std_logic;
           tx_data   : in  std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
           tx_out    : out std_logic
    );    
end serialtx;
architecture behavioral of serialtx is
    type ofstate is (IDLE, START_bit, STOP_bit);
    signal state, nextstate      : ofstate;
    signal parity_bit, tx_enable : std_logic;
begin
    process
        variable count, p_val : integer := 0;
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk = '1' and tx_enable = '1')then
            if(reset = '1')then
                tx_out <= '0';
            else
                case state is
                    when IDLE =>
                        tx_out    <= '0';
                        nextstate <= START_bit;
                    when START_bit =>
                        count := count+1;
                        if(count >= 0 and count < 7)then
                            for b in p_val to data_width-1 loop
                                tx_out <= tx_data(p_val);
                            end loop;
                        elsif(count = 7)then
                            tx_out <= parity_bit;
                            p_val  := p_val+1;
                        elsif(count = 8) then
                            tx_out    <= '1';
                            nextstate <= STOP_bit;
                            count     := 0;
                        end if;
                    when STOP_bit =>
          --if--data to be sent is completed then    
                        tx_out    <= '1';
                        tx_enable <= '0';
          --else    
                        nextstate <= IDLE;
          --end if;    
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect.  You do understand SDI-12's byte frame format, but you should also understand the SDI-12 commands that you want to transmit to an SDI-12 sensor.

All SDI-12 commands are comprised of ASCII characters, transmitted using a byte frame format of 1 start bit, 7 data bits, 1 parity bit (even), and 1 stop bit.

It seems you are trying to transmit "C,P" plus 3 extra bits to an SDI-12 sensor.  Under the SDI-12 specification this is invalid.  Padding the 3 extra bits (what are they for?) with 4 more bits just to get to 7 bits makes no sense, and "C,P" is not a valid SDI-12 command (unless the sensor address is "C" and ",P" is an SDI-12 extended command, which is another topic).

You need to transmit valid SDI-12 commands to SDI-12 sensors.

The first character of an SDI-12 command is always a sensor address, which is a single, printable, ASCII character.  The last character of an SDI-12 command is "!" (ASCII 33 decimal).

Responses from sensors are terminated with a carriage return/line feed pair (ASCII 13 decimal + ASCII 10 decimal).

The simplest SDI-12 command is the Acknowledge Active Command.  This command is used to see if a specific sensor is connected to the SDI-12 bus.

For example, if the sensor's address is "0" (ASCII 32 decimal), the Acknowledge Active command is:

```
0!
```

If this is transferred to an SDI-12 sensor in the proper byte frame format, at 1200 baud, conforming to the electrical requirements of the SDI-12 Specification, and if a sensor having address "0" is at the other end, you will get this response back from the sensor:

```
0<CR><LF>
```

The SDI-12 Specification lists all of the valid SDI-12 commands. You can get a copy of it at:  [www.sdi-12.org](http://www.sdi-12.org).

Answer (score 0):

> what data should I transmit in the last for bits i.e.,_ _ _ _

Why not pad your input data with 0s, up to the next multiple of 7 data bits in length?